# Preconditioned Conjugate Gradient (PCG) cannot start in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, iteration

I'm trying to implement a PCG in MATLAB with no preconditioner.
Ax=b, in which A is a 100 by 100 2D laplacian matrix and b is all 1s.

```
n=10;
e = ones(n,1);
spe = spdiags([e -2*e e], -1:1,n,n);
Iz = speye(n);
A = kron(Iz,spe)+kron(spe,Iz);
b = ones(size(A,1),1);
[x0,fl0,rr0,it0,rv0] = pcg(A,b,1e-8,100);
```

However, it turns out the iteration cannot start and the flag

> fl0=4

It means

> One of the scalar quantities calculated during pcg became too small or
>   too large to continue computing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that in order to use PCG, A must be positive definite. So use -A instead of A should be okay.